# upgrading from sitecore 6.6 to sitecore 7.0

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to update a Sitecore 6.6 instance to Sitecore 7.0. After logging in to the Sitecore administrative interface and launching the content editor, I receive the error:

> Access is denied: 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.RenderingDatasource'.

Please help!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark... but have you cleared your browser cache after completing the upgrade?

Comment: Is the upgrade done with package Sitecore 7.0 rev. 130424.update and changing file web.config, Sitecore.Analytics and Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config... And have you check the installed (marketplace) modules on compatiblitie?

Comment: Can you provide more information such as the stack trace from the log

Comment: Yeah, I have done with the cache cleanup and followed the upgrade process as from Sdn, installed package from installation wizard and then changed in configuration files, didn't run analytics dB script as we are not using that.

Comment: I have used sitecore 7.0 Rev. 130424 initial release update package for upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs. It's resolved now.  There was some issue in installed package. Installed package again resolved the issue.